# Can you pack UV's according to material ID?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

I have A LOT of uv islands for a character and despite my best efforts, I can't optimize space well manually. is there a way to automatically pack uv's **SUCH THAT** islands with the same material are adjacent? Via a plugin or script or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn on the UV-edit mesh sync in the UV editor then you can select uv islands by materials in the materials tab. So select one material then hit Ctrl-P in the UV editor and repeat it with all of the materials.
[image]